# Trying to parse Json but invalid variable name

Tags: java, json

[image: Error]

I'm trying to parse Json data however even after I define the jsonData variable in the line above, it shows up as undeclared when I try to insert it in the line `JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(jsonData);`

I have these dependencies installed as well

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

I have checked the Json data to be valid after printing it.

Please help me parse the data. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your `jsonData` Variable inside a loop block. Your variable is out of scope when your runtime leaves the loop.

You would implement it like this:

```java
var jsonData = "";
while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    jsonData += inputLine;
}
```

Or you can use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: Alright, I just did that but now I am getting another error- "new JSONParser().parse(jsonData);" the line is underlined with red. When I click on it, it gives me to options, surround with try/catch or add throws declaration. Am I supposed to choose from them? I am new to programming.

Comment: The `parse()` method throws an exception (or error) when parsing your JSON data, for example when your data structure is invalid. you would surround the method with a `try { ...} catch(Exception e) {...}` block to handle the exception when it has been thrown. Remember that every curly bracket pair declares a block and variables declared inside can not be accessed from the "outside".

Comment: Also @Diongere, when you say "I have these dependencies", it is technically wrong. Dependencies are what extra libraries you have in the classpath, those libraries are a bunch of util classes which help you do stuff.

What you have shared are nothing but imports. Those classes are defined in some other class files. You have just imported them to use them in this file.

I am sure, with more deep dive, this will make sense, just wanted to let you know.